# How to avoid duplicate logic data in SQL schema based on a use case?

Tags: sql, mysql

Use case :

- A client can have cars
- A client can organize cars using groups (he can create new groups and assign cars)
- A car has to be owned by a **single** client but group is optional (depending on client adding it to a group or not)

Here is my model :

| client |
| --- |
| id |

| group |
| --- |
| id |
| clientId |

| car |
| --- |
| id |
| clientId |
| groupId |

I cannot rely on the group linked to client to make a link car-group-client since groups are not required.
So i added a clientId in the car table to make sure every car is owned by a client (cannot be clientless).

But this option has duplicate data since a car is linked to a client in the car table and also using the group table.
Depending on the code, it can leads to the **mistake** : two different clients owning the same car (one linked with the clientId from the car table and the other owning the group the car is assigned to).

Since the model is supposed to guarantee the data consistency, what would be the best practice in this case ?

Creating a default group for each client, reprenting the groupless cars can be a better option ?

Comment: @JonasMetzler actually car can only be owned by a single client, i updated post to be more specific

Comment: I would use application logic (or mysql triggers if you really insist on using just mysql) to prevent adding cars owned by different clients to the group owner client. Btw your data is not duplicate as client ids represent different levels of ownership

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question, following logic should be applied:

1. Every car must have a client (either directly or via group).
2. Groups are not required.
3. A car must not have both a client and a group.

We can implement above logic using a check constraint on the car table.

We want to say that exactly one of the two columns clientid or groupid must not be `NULL`. The clientid has the higher priority because groups are not required according to your description.

So we can do following:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_car CHECK 
  (CASE WHEN clientid IS NULL 
    THEN groupid IS NOT NULL 
    ELSE groupid IS NULL END = 1);
```

or alternatively, with the same logic:

```
CONSTRAINT ck_car CHECK 
  (CASE WHEN clientid IS NOT NULL 
    THEN groupid IS NULL 
    ELSE groupid IS NOT NULL END = 1);
```

This check constraint can either be placed in your create table command or added afterwards with an alter table command.

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g6UBrcib)

**Some important notes:**

1. We need of course correct primary keys and foreign keys to prevent incorrect data will be inserted.
2. It might be better/faster to do that in the application rather than in the database.
3. Data is not generally redundant because it appears in different tables. The logic shown in this answer is really hard and we should be sure that's really what we want to do. Why can't a car have both a client and a group (especially when the group's owner is the same person as the client of the car)?

It's up to you to think about these things.